# How to change the layout of master slider from 'partialview' to 'fillwidth' only on tablet/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using MasterSlider.js to make the carousal, I want to give it partialview on desktop and fillwidth view on tablet and mobile. I am trying to change it through detecting the window width but there is something wrong in my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = new MasterSlider();
        slider.setup('masterslider' , {
            width:700,
            height:466,
            space:5,
            loop:true,
            view:'fadeFlow',
            layout:'partialview',
            grabCursor:false,
            centerControls:false,
            autohide:false,
            view:"fadeBasic",

        });
        slider.control('arrows' , {autohide:false});


   if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        slider.setup('masterslider' , {

                    layout:'fillwidth',
                    grabCursor:false,
                    centerControls:false,
                });
            }
</script>
```

One more thing I am using fadeBasic option to make the previous and next image fade out by default it is applying opactiy 0.4, is there any way I make it 0.8. Opacity is applying on run time.

Just for reference I am using this slider:
http://www.mercurycustom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/partialview/partialview3.html

Here is a running demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dopNrM

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? What's the output in Firefox console?

Comment: here it is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dopNrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
slider.control('arrows');
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
  slider.setup('masterslider', {
    layout: 'fillwidth',
    grabCursor: false,
    centerControls: false,
  });
} else {
  slider.setup('masterslider', {
    width: 760,
    height: 400,
    space: 10,
    loop: true,
    view: 'fadeFlow',
    layout: 'partialview',
  });
}
```